# GCDAsyncSocket : Socket Connection does not send host event

Tags: ios, sockets

I am developing application in iOS which is based on socket communication. I am using **GCDAsyncSocket** for socket management. I have never worked on socket before this. It is working fine when device request to socket and it gives proper response. Problem is that if device doesn't make any request and Server socket want to send event, then it is not receiving. So as per my understanding:

1. Does it mean socket only send data to client when it is requested, means socket can't send data/event to client if it is not requested?

OR

2. Does **GCDAsyncSocket** works in way that when a request is made from client then only it will listen for data?

Can anyone please correct me? and help me in the case, how to recive event/data from host if request is not made?

Thanks